# Geometric multipliers for $\min \frac{1}{2} (x_1^2 +x_2^2) ~~ s.t. ~ x_1\leq1$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am reading about geometric multipliers and I am trying to understand an example from here [1]. The visualization of this example is given below. According to the text, there is a unique geometric multiplier $\mu^*=1$. Could you please someone explain how the shaded part of the figure is drawn and how the solution is computed? Shall we draw the problem in three dimensions?

[image].

<sup>[1] Nonlinear Programming, Bertsekas.</sup>

Comment: As far I can see $f(x)$ is minimized if $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$

Comment: And that correspond to the point $(g(0),f(0)) = (-1,0)$.

Comment: The shaded area is just the parametric plot of $(g(x),f(x))$ as $x$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example, with $x=(1,2)$ we could get the point $(0, {5 \over 2})$.

Comment: The normal to the surface $S$ at the minimiser is vertical, so the normal is a multiple of $(0,1)$, I am not sure what the $\mu^*$ is above. Note that the minimiser is not constrained by $g$.